# Renaming items in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python list as below:

```
['item1','item2','item3']
```

I am trying to rename the items in the list as

```
['person1','person2','person3']
```

Could anyone guide me. Thanks

Comment: @khelwood sorry was a typo, meant it to be item3.. Have edited the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With speed in mind and for a lot of elements:

```
%%timeit
arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
arr = np.char.replace(arr, 'item', 'person')
```

16.4 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
arr = [x.replace('item', 'person') for x in arr]
```

1.42 µs ± 174 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

### Even for 100.000 Elements it seems to be slower to use numpy:

**Numpy**: 177 ms ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

**ListComprehension**: 35.7 ms ± 3.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Even **Pandas.Series** is slower on my tests:

```
%%timeit
series.str.replace('item', 'person')
```

144 ms ± 4.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace specific elements by specific values, do this:

```
In [521]: items = ['item1','item2','item3']

In [522]: dic = {'item1':'person1', 'item2':'human', 'item3':'person3'}

In [523]: [dic.get(n, n) for n in items]
Out[523]: ['person1', 'human', 'person3']
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to change `"item"` to `"person"`, and you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions) to generate a new list.

```
items = ['item1','item2','item3']
people = [item.replace('item', 'person') for item in items]
```

Result:

```
['person1', 'person2', 'person3']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could I please ask one more edit. What if I wanted to rename item1 as person and item2 as human. How could I modify your reply.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one digit at the end of basic list, you could use:

```
>>> out = [] 
>>> input = ['item1','item2','item3']
>>> for i in input:
        out.append('person{}'.format(i[-1]))


>>> out
['person1', 'person2', 'person3']
```

EDIT:

I also came across this solution, which also works for numbers greater than 9:

```
>>> items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
>>> out = []

>>> for item in items:
        out.append('person{}'.format(int(filter(str.isdigit,item))))

>>> out
['person1', 'person2', 'person3']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have a list of 20 columns and each time the list can have columns in any combination.